# How do I append new line in pug?

Tags: jquery, pug

I'm trying to append data and have them appear on a new line

I've tried

```
      $.each(data,function(label) { // loop over result
        $("#labels").append(label._id+":"+label.label + 'br');
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you just need to inline the br like so

```
      $.each(data,function(label) { // loop over result         
        $("#labels").append(data[label].label + '<br/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also wrap the data in a block element like `<div>` or `<p>` to appear in a new line.